# How do I ignore the first column in SQL Insert instruction via Excel VBA?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

To be more clear,

I have the following table:

```
+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| ID              | Key          | Region      | Branch      |
+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| INT PRIMARY KEY | VARCHAR(100) | VARCHAR(50) | VARCHAR(50) |
+-----------------+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I need to insert a new `Key`, `Region` and `Branch`, ignoring the first column ID since it is a **Primary Key**.

I am trying with this code:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO ASSETS (Key, Region, Branch) VALUES ('ABCF1258EF', 'MY_REGION', 'MY_BRANCH');"
```

---

```
Public Sub connectDB(sql As String, ConnectionString As String)

    Set DBcon = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set DBCom = New ADODB.Command

    DBcon.Open ConnectionString
    DBCom.ActiveConnection = DBcon
    DBCom.CommandText = sql
    DBCom.Execute

End Sub
```

Although I am getting the error

`Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement`

It works well if I insert a new ID getting the last ID and appending + 1 but this is not a good practice.

I do it normally when I use MySQL connection but with MS Access it is not working.

Comment: Is ID an autonumber column?

Comment: yes @TimWilliams it is

Comment: @krishKM I said **ignoring the first column ID**

Comment: **sorry my mistake** try sending `null` as value for ID.

Comment: Is that the full error you're getting?  Can you run that SQL in Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling all day I found out that I can't use the word `KEY` as column name.
It's strange because the SQL instruction works well if I execute the same snippet inside MS Access, but it doesn't work in Excel when sending instructions to the database.

So, I changed the column for `KEY_` and everything is working normally.

Answer (score 0):

No space between table name and left bracket in Insert statement - so it should be

```sql
sql = "INSERT INTO ASSETS(Key, Region, Branch) VALUES ('ABCF1258EF','MY_REGION','MY_BRANCH');"
```